# React Native navigation with onPress function in for loop

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make an image-gallery in React Native.

What I currently have is a site which looks like this:
[imageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0lZa.jpg)

The images are only 9 test-images which are required in an array like this:

```
    var imagesLoaded =
[
      require('./image_1.jpg'),
      require('./image_2.jpg'),
      require('./image_3.jpg'),
      require('./image_4.jpg'),
      require('./image_5.jpg'),
      require('./image_6.jpg'),
      require('./image_7.jpg'),
      require('./image_8.jpg'),
      require('./image_9.jpg')
];
```

What I now want to be able to do is to tap on an image which results in a new page being opened with the tapped image alone on a black background.

This is the code for the gallery:

```
class ImageView extends Component
{
      static navigationOptions = 
      {
            title: 'ImageView',
      };

      render()
      {
            const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

            var images = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                  var imageString = 'Image #' + (i+1);

                  images.push(
                        <TouchableHighlight key={i} onPress={() => navigate('ImageTap', {imageSrc: imagesLoaded[i%9]})}>
                              <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                                    <Image source={imagesLoaded[i%9]} style={styles.images}/>
                                    <Text style={styles.imageText}>{imageString}</Text>
                              </View>
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                  )
            }

            return (
                  <ScrollView>
                        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                              {images}
                        </View>
                  </ScrollView>
            );
      }
}
```

And this is the code for the new page which is supposed to open:

```
class ImageTap extends Component
{
      static navigationOptions = 
      {
            title: 'ImageView',
      };

      render()
      {
            const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

            return (
                  <View style={{backgroundColor: 'black', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <Image source={params.imageSrc} style={{flex: 1}}/>
                  </View>
            );
      }
}
```

But what happens is that always the last image of the foor-loop is opened. Regardless of which image is tapped.If I give the iterator i to the new page as a parameter and log it I always get 199. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because when onPress() is called it takes the value of variable 'i'. Since you are looping using that variable it will go till the last value. So when onPress will be called, it will use that value (because it is not binding each value of 'i' to each onPress()).

A better solution would be you extract out your image component in another component and pass it the image source and handle onPress there.

Something like this:

your **ImageComponent**. Pass it source, imageString and onPress function as props.

```
const GalleryImage = ({ source, imageString, onPress }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress(src)}>
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                <Image source={source} style={styles.images}/>
                <Text style={styles.imageText}>{imageString}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
};

const styles = {
    imageContainer: {
     ....
    },
    images: {
     ....
    },
    imageTex: {
     ....
    }
}

export default GalleryImage;
```

your **ImageView component**

```
import GalleryImage from './GallerImage';

class ImageView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleNavigation = this.handleNavigation.bind(this);
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'ImageView',
    };

    handleNavigation(source) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ImageTap', {imageSrc: source});
    }

    renderGalleryImages() {
        return imagesLoaded.map(
            (src, i) => {
               <GalleryImage
                   key={i},
                   source={src},
                   imageString = {'Image #' + (i+1)},
                   onPress= {this.handleNavigation}
               />
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
              <ScrollView>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                          {this.renderGalleryImages()}
                    </View>
              </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Also, better not to use index as key for elements as that might hurt performance if items move in the list: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I tried to run your code, but my ImageView is now completly empty. I tried to find the mistake, but except for removing the commas in <GalleryImage> I couldn't find what's wrong

Comment: I copy pasted your code only and separated out Image component. I didn't run the code I wrote in the answer. It is just an idea about how you can implement gallery that should open the correct image. The problem with your code is just that it is always taking last value of 'i'. But the way I wrote the code should fix that issue. Instead of using this code you can just use the idea of passing imageurl and callback to GalleryImage component. Also can you please put log statements and check if you are getting correct props in your GallerImage component or not?

Comment: Also if the image is not visible then there may be some issue with styling.